# Error in .computeSumFactors: cells should have non-zero library sizes

Tags: rna-seq, r, scran

While trying to run the following code in `R`:

```
list_of_sce <- list()
# Looping though the UMI_count 'split_factor' columns at a time
split_factor = 500
for(i in seq(1,ncols, split_factor)) {
  num_loop = floor(i / split_factor) + 1
  idx = ncols
  if (i + split_factor < ncols) {
    idx = i + split_factor
  } 
sce <- SingleCellExperiment(list(counts=UMI_count[, i : idx]))
# Normalization of the dataset containing 
# heterogenous cell data (different cell types)
clusters <- quickCluster(sce)
sce <- computeSumFactors(sce, cluster=clusters)
list_of_sce[[num_loop]] <- sce
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error in .computeSumFactors(assay(x, i = assay.type), subset.row = 
subset.row,  : 
cells should have non-zero library sizes
```

There are `warnings`, so when I run `warnings()` command I see the following:

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In .computeSumFactors(assay(x, i = assay.type), subset.row = 
subset.row,  ... :
encountered negative size factor estimates
2: In .computeSumFactors(assay(x, i = assay.type), subset.row = 
subset.row,  ... :
encountered negative size factor estimates
3:...
...
39:....
```

I do not understand why is this happening, and how to debug it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the library size of the samples? computeSumFactors is failing because it can't compute the library size. I am not sure if your code is working as intended, shouldn't the `sce` be inside your loop?

Comment: Do you have a sample with all 0s?

Comment: Your code is different from another question you posted ([here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/3123/48)). Is this the same data/problem as in the linked question?

Comment: It is the same. Where is the difference? Can't see it. These are related but different questions, so I asked them separately.